# Facebook graph api. Get photos from albums

Tags: facebook, json, api, facebook-graph-api

Please help me to make a correct request to Facebook api. Now i've got:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=photos
```

As the result I get very big Json with a lot of unnecessary info. I tried to do something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=photos?fields=source,name,id
```

or like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=photos&fields=source,name,id
```

But [graph api explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), returned the same big response, or i caught an error.
Any ideas how to do more compact response with only necessary info?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to fetch?  Album cover photos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may only use `fields` with properties that exists for objects.

By issuing GET request to next URL you'll get list of albums ids only:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=id&access_token=...
```

Same can be achieved by running next [`FQL`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query on [`album`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/) table:

```
SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me()
```

Actually `albums` connection of `user` doesn't really contain list of [`photo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) objects but [`album`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) (which have `photos` connection). So to get photos owned by user you'll need iterate over all of his object and getting photos for every album. Again you may use `fields` argument to limit resulting data. This can be done faster if using [batch requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

Or With [`FQL`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) it may be done like this (two tables [`photo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) and [`album`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/) involved):

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())
```

Answer (score 29):

Actually there is a better way to achieve this, nesting the request

Passing albums as a parameter, and then filter the fields from the connection photos that you want to, for example here I got just everything I need from albums and photos, also this results can be limited

```
me?fields=albums.fields(id,name,cover_photo,photos.fields(name,picture,source))
```

Comment: This is really awesome..I was searching for this!

Comment: and if you want fields for the cover_photo as well : 
`me?fields=albums.fields(id,name,cover_photo.fields(id,name,source,picture),photos.fields(name,picture,source))`

Comment: +1. Sergio, given your answer here, I bet you know the answer to this Facebook Graph nesting question too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57454155/470749

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is getting album ids first and then iterate over them making this API call:

```
<ALBUM-ID>/photos?fields=name,source,id
```

I tested this in graph explorer and it retrieved a reasonable (and readable) json object

Answer (score 2):

For photo urls:

1. Ensure that you are an Admin of the Facebook Page.
2. go to :
   http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
3. In the API Navigator, you can see "/me" will bring up the basic information of yourself.
4. Try typing in "/me/accounts" to see if you can see anything. It should give you an error.
5. Click on "Get Access Token"
6. a window will pop-up. Navigate to "Extended Permissions"
7. Select "manage_pages"
8. Click "Get Access Token"
9. Now try "/me/accounts" again. You should see a list of Groups inside the viewing window.
10. Select the Page you want, and click on the "id" field
11. Next, on the left window, you can see "Node:  " and a + sign. Click on the + sign to see what are the options you have.
12. Click on the + sign and scroll down to "connections" and select "Albums"
13. The child-level, select "Photos"
14. The "Photos" child-level, select "source"
15. Now click "Submit" on the right hand side. You will see a JSON returned with the url of all the photos in your Facebook Page.
16. Copy the URL - https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=albums.fields(photos.fields(source)) and plug it into your browser. You should see a JSON of all your photos.

Answer (score 2):

Each album is a object like user object in facebook, to get photos in that particular album you have to request some thing like below

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{ALBUM_ID}?fields=photos&access_token="xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the album list type :

`me?fields=albums`

after that type :

`album_id/photos?fields=source`

to get the photos of that particular album

Answer (score 1):

GETTING ALBUM_ID

```
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil)
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/albums", parameters: ["fields" : "id"], httpMethod: "GET").start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                self.arrdata = data["data"]?.value(forKey: "id") as! [String ]
            }
        })
    }
```

with above code you will get album_Id and then with that id we can get image like this :
GETTING IMAGES FROM ALBUM_ID

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\(album_Id)/photos", parameters: ["fields": "source"], httpMethod: "GET").start(completionHandler: { (connection, result1, error) -> Void in
       if (error == nil)
       {
           let data1:[String:AnyObject] = result1 as! [String : AnyObject]
           let arrdata:[String] = data1["data"]?.value(forKey: "source") as! [String ]
           for item in arrdata
           {
               let url = NSURL(string: item )
               let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
               let image = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
               self.imgArr.append(image!)
           }
        }
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request('GET', '/me/albums?fields=id,name,cover_photo,photos{images{source}},description')
```

it will show the albums with description and photos with different resolution of that album.
**This will need access token**

Comment: Thank you that works, but I have a question; Can I only have images with a specific resolution? For Example I want to query only 600x600 image for each photo in an album.

Answer (score 1):

for **Swift 5**

**first get albums id like this**

```
func getAlbumsData()
{

        GraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,name,albums{name,picture}"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, userResult, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("error occured \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
            else if userResult != nil {
                print("Login with FB is success")
                print()



                let fbResult:[String:AnyObject] = userResult as! [String : AnyObject]

                self.albumsPhotos = (fbResult["albums"] as! [String:AnyObject])["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
                self.tblFbAlbums.reloadData()




            }
        })
    }
```

**then get albums image with this method**

```
func fetchalbumsPhotosWithID() {


        let graphRequest : GraphRequest  = GraphRequest(graphPath: "\(album_Id)/photos", parameters: ["fields": "source"] )

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")

                let data =  result as! [String:Any]


            }
        })

    }
```

**album_Id is a number you get from getAlbumsData()**

Answer (score 0):

Why is the data unnecessary? Did it return something like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "ID",
         "from": {
            "name": "Hadrian de Oliveira",
            "id": "100000238267321"
         },
         "name": "Cover Photos",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=FBID&id=ID&aid=AID",
         "cover_photo": "ID",
         "privacy": "everyone",
         "count": 2,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2011-10-06T01:31:24+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-02-22T17:29:50+0000",
         "can_upload": false
      },
```

?

Comment: Probably yes. I don't need all these fields, I want only photo links.

Comment: How did you came up to get that result @JohnKozlov

Answer (score 0):

loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email","user_friends","user_photos");

this permistion required

Answer (score -1):

```
for android
        new GraphRequest(
                facebookToken,
                String.format("/%s/photos", idAlbum),
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONArray photoArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                        photosAlbumAfterPagination = response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("paging").getJSONObject("cursors").getString("after");
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type type = new TypeToken<List<FacebookPhotoResponse>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        List<FacebookPhotoResponse> list = gson.fromJson(photoArray.toString(), type);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```