# Albums and photos in Facebook API Graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm doing an app in facebook and I want some things with API Graph but I don't know how to access.

With this tool 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/' y can see some photos if I select albums and then photos like that fields=albums.fields(photos) but if I do the same in my source I don't know how to do.
I can write "idx($facebook->api('/me/albums/', 'data', array()); and it's good, but how I can to write albums.fields(photos) here?

Is like that [Facebook graph api. Get photos from albums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486370/facebook-graph-api-get-photos-from-albums) but with api graph, not with fql.

Thanks.

Comment: I have one problem. Whith this tool, I can read the comments of photos for example, but it have a limit. I would like to read all of them. Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy a path directly from the Graph API explorer into a Facebook SDK `api` call.

So you'd want your call to be

```
id($facebook->api('/me/albums?fields=photos', 'data', array());
```